# MapBox get div element of Marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am initially pushing MapBox Marker objects to an array via:

```
var el = document.createElement('div' + index);
el.className = 'marker';
deviceMarkers.push(new mapboxgl.Marker(el, { offset: [-50 / 2, -50 / 2] }).setLngLat([device.lat, device.lon]).addTo(map));
```

Elsewhere in the code, I extract the marker via:

```
var deviceMarker = deviceMarkers[index];
```

I would like to be able to get 'el' from deviceMarker object, in order to alter the icon size, orientation etc. dynamically. How can I extract 'el' as the original div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `deviceMarker.getElement()` – this function is currently undocumented but public. I will work on getting it added to the documentation.

Comment: You legend. I'll give it a go later.

Comment: This worked great. Would you be able to assist with the follow-up? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072617/programmatically-change-offset-of-mapbox-marker-via-javascript