# Programmatically change OFFSET of MapBox Marker via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056083/mapbox-get-div-element-of-marker) I asked yesterday...

I am adding MapBox Markers to an array like so:

```
var el = document.createElement('div' + index);
el.className = 'marker';
deviceMarkers.push(new mapboxgl.Marker(el, { offset: [-50 / 2, -50 / 2] }).setLngLat([device.lat, device.lon]).addTo(map));
```

Elsewhere in the code, I extract the marker via:

```
var deviceMarker = deviceMarkers[index];
```

**I now need to be able to change the offset of *deviceMarker* programmatically in javascript, to ensure that the image is still centred as the div resizes with zoom.**

Can it be done, and if so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "marker offset"? AFAIK there is no thing called "offset" associated with marker other then the z-index offset

Comment: It's in the first code block, mate: { offset: [-50 / 2, -50 / 2] } I want to be able to change this dynamically. It's a positional offset so that the image being used for the marker is centred. Obviously this has to change as the image size changes.

Comment: There is no way to do this with the current API. I would recommend you just make a new marker with the new offset and the existing element (i.e. `new mapboxgl.Marker(oldMarker.getElement(), ...` and then remove the old marker)

Comment: Thanks @mollymerp. Your help is much appreciated again.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer @mollymerp and I will accept it. Tar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the current API. I would recommend you just make a new marker with the new offset and the existing element (i.e. `new mapboxgl.Marker(oldMarker.getElement(), ...)` and then remove the old marker)